# Audio filters in Firefox OS

Tags: audio, firefox-os

Is it possible in Firefox OS to create a filtering application such as a fancy equalizer which can apply its filter to all audio going to the device audio outputs independent of the source of that audio?

Comment: Have you seen the Web Audio docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API  Look at the Voice-change-o-matic  Firefox OS example https://github.com/mdn/voice-change-o-matic

Answer (score 0):

No, you only have control over sound that your apps create at the moment. No way of plugging into the device audio output.